# Angularjs: How to access specific item in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a custom directive that consists of a list of buttons dynamically created through `ng-repeat` as follows:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="toggleButtonController" ng-init="init()" id="parent">
    <div ng-repeat="btn in setting" style="display:inline">
        <button class="btn" ng-bind="btn.name" ng-click="click(btn)" ng-class="getClass(btn, toggleButton.selected)"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
 var app = angular.module('toggleButtonMod', [])
 app.directive('toggleButton', function() {
 return {
     restrict: 'E',
     scope: {
         setting: '='
     },
     templateUrl: "app/Shared/togglebutton/toggleButtonView.html"
 }
})
app.controller("toggleButtonController", function($scope) {
 $scope.init = function() {
     $scope.setupContent();
 }
 $scope.setupContent = function() {
     $scope.toggleButton = {selected: null};
 }
 $scope.click = function(btn) {
    $scope.toggleButton.selected = btn;
 }
 $scope.getClass = function(btn, toggleSelected){
    if(btn === toggleSelected){
        return 'btn-primary';
    }else{
        return 'btn-default';
    }
 }

})
```

The scenario here is to create a service or any other better implementations to change the `ng-class` of a specific button in the `ng-repeat`.

For example:

```
app.service('selectDefault', function(index) {
   //set button #2 to have ng-class="btn-primary"
}
```

Comment: If you only want to add class to nth button, you can try to use $index

Comment: What will be the condition??

Comment: @VicJordan no conditions..just pass the index and it will set the nth index button to have that class.

Comment: do you need to highlight button associated with _current_ route? router components I used provided function for such a check

Answer (score 0):

I'm not definitely sure if this is what you're looking for. But this snippet will show how to add class on the fly in `ng-repeat` using a service. Hope it helps!

**https://jsfiddle.net/cgdmqt8o/**

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `ng-class` to:

```
ng-class="{'btn-primary':(btn === toggleSelected), 'btn-default':(btn != toggleSelected)}"
```

That is assuming the variable `toggleSelected` is set somewhere in your code, although I don't see it being set in the above sample.

Comment: I tried this, however I want to provide an api for the directive to enable other controllers to set the class for the button.